# Get ListObject using VBA by range

Tags: excel, vba, range

is there a way to get a listobject variable from a cell or range inside it? Sort of like this:

```
Dim someTable as ListObject, someRange as Range
Set TBL=SomeFunction(someRange)
```

How would SomeFunction be? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `Range` object has a `listObject` property.

If `someRange` overlaps cells within a `ListObject`'s range, then use

```
Set someTable = someRange.ListObject
```